# Doing simple Bash file write in Python

Tags: python, bash, file-io

I'd like to replace this BASH expression:

```
expr $COUNT + 1 > $COUNT_FILE
```

with the equivalent in Python.  I've come up with this:

```
subprocess.call("expr " + str(int(COUNT)+1) + " > " + COUNT_FILE, shell=True)
```

Or (maybe a bit better):

```
 subprocess.call("echo " + str(int(COUNT)+1) + " > " + COUNT_FILE, shell=True)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Based on your input:

```
def out_to_file(out_string, file_name, append='w'):
    with open(file_name, append) as f:
        f.write(out_string+'\n')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open(COUNT_FILE, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(int(COUNT)+1)+'\n')
```

Comment: Is the file closed after this?

Comment: Yes, the [with-statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) automatically closes the file when Python leaves the `with`-block.

Answer (score 3):

Use python to write files, not shell. Your code is not replacing any bash expression, you are still running it in bash...

Instead try:

```
with open(COUNT_FILE, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(int(COUNT) + 1) + "\n")

    # or python 2:
    # print >> f, int(COUNT) + 1

    # python 3
    # print(int(COUNT) + 1, file=f)
```

The file will be automatically closed after the `with` block is exited.

Comment: Just throwing this out there... the third method you showed (python 3 version) can be accessed with python 2 by throwing a `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the file.  I'm sure you already knew this, but not sure if the OP did.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the shell, write directly to the file using Python's I/O functions:

```
with open(count_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(count + 1) + '\n')
```

The `with` statement takes care of closing the file afterwards, so it's safer.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have `expr` computing the result, the Python instruction would be:

```
import subprocess
count_file= ...   #  It needs to be set somewhere in the Python program
count= ...        #  Idem
subprocess.call(["expr",str(count),"+","1"], stdout=open(count_file,"wb") )
f.close()
```

If you prefer doing the math in Python, you can use

```
with open(count_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(count+1)+'\n')
```

If you want to retrieve environmental variables:

```
import os
count_file= os.environ['COUNT_FILE']
count= int( os.environ['COUNT'] )
```

If you want to make it more general, you can also use

```
count= ...        #  It needs to be set somewhere in the Python program
print( count + 1 )
```

and perform redirection when invoking Python:

```
$ myIncrementer.py >$COUNT_FILE
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  Thanks Antti.  Corrected.

Comment: I mean it is NOT computing the value with expr

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  OMG, you are absolutely right.  I mentally invented/corrected 50% of the instruction.